# Extending Menu Items on all screens for android .

Tags: android, menu

I am using actionbarsherlock.
Using the following code I have created a menu for the home screen

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AboutApp.class); // Start About.java Activity
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case R.id.feedback:
            Intent j = new Intent(this, SendFeedback.class); 
            startActivity(j);
            return true;
       default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How do I extend this menu to all the screens across the entire app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BaseClass` that `extends Activity` (or `FragmentActivity`) and let other sublcass it.

```
OtherClass extends BaseClass
```

Since `BaseClass extends SherlockFragmentActivity`, `OtherClass` will extends it too.

Comment: I am already extending SherlockFragmentActivity. How do I go about extending a Baseactivity to other classes ?

Comment: yes. This makes much more sense. EDIT - this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Create a BaseActivity including this functionality and make rest of your activities extend this activity.